# error: incompatible types: int cannot be converted to Toolbar R.drawable.ic_drawer & cannot find symbol "mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle("

Tags: android, android-studio, android-drawable, androidx

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import androidx.multidex.MultiDex;
import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;
```

and error this "error: incompatible types: int cannot be converted to Toolbar R.drawable.ic_drawer & cannot find symbol "mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle("

```
mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
        this,                  /* host Activity */
        mDrawerLayout,         /* DrawerLayout object */
        R.drawable.ic_drawer,  /* nav drawer icon to replace 'Up' caret */
        R.string.drawer_open,  /* "open drawer" description */
        R.string.drawer_close  /* "close drawer" description */
        ) {
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using this [constructor](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/appcompat/app/ActionBarDrawerToggle#ActionBarDrawerToggle(android.app.Activity,%20androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout,%20androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar,%20int,%20int)):

```
ActionBarDrawerToggle(Activity activity,
          DrawerLayout drawerLayout, 
          Toolbar toolbar, 
          int openDrawerContentDescRes, 
          int closeDrawerContentDescRes)
```

The issue is with

```
R.drawable.ic_drawer,  /* nav drawer icon to replace 'Up' caret */
```

You have to pass the `Toolbar`.